# Limiting portion of site to screenshot with HTML2Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html2canvas

I would like to make a screenshot of the body of a page, but since it's a very long one and the parsing takes too much I would like to restrain the height to scan.

Does anyone know how can I do that?